# Can't install pyinstaller for python 2.7

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I try to install pyinstaller through pip and i get a syntax error. It succesfully downloads package and components then throws the error. The error is showing me an f string. I know that f strings came with python3 and i am trying to install old version of pyinstaller which is 3.6 and compatible with python 2.7. My command is `pip install pyinstaller==3.6`. Versions:
**python 2.7
pip 20.3.4**

Comment: please do `python --version` and give us the output, 
if its says version 3 then just do `python install pyinstaller`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen it is 2.7.17

Comment: Python 2 reached [end-of-life](https://devguide.python.org/versions/) almost 4 years ago. Why are you trying to use it at all? The [Status of Python Versions](https://devguide.python.org/versions/) page shows that even 3.7 has reached EOL.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that you should be avoiding python2.7, use `python2 -m pip install pyinstaller==3.6`. This way you are certain that the version of pip you are using is in the same environment as you code.